# Why does using RecyclerView instead of ListView give me white screen result when all of my data come from same Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I want to show data which come from [GitHubApi](http://api.github.com) in RecyclerView but I can't do it. I can show this data in ListView.I can use RecyclerView with my own `List<>` collections data. When I want to use RecyclerView with Retrofit, my application show me a white screen instead of throwing an error. I can not solve this problem.

```
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<P006StrongClass>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<P006StrongClass>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            RecyclerView.Adapter adapter=new P006RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),response.body());
recyclerViewP006.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(P006RetrofitRecyclerView.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            recyclerViewP006.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        }
    });
```

This is my RecyclerView Adapter class:

```
    public class P006RecyclerViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<P006RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder2> {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
List<P006StrongClass> p006StrongClassList;
MyViewHolder2 myViewHolder2;
public P006RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,List<P006StrongClass> p006StrongClassList) {
    layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.p006StrongClassList=p006StrongClassList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder2 onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.p006customrow, parent, false);
    myViewHolder2=new MyViewHolder2(view);
    return myViewHolder2;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder2 holder, int position) {
    P006StrongClass p006StrongClassTek=p006StrongClassList.get(position);
    holder.textViewP006.setText(p006StrongClassTek.getId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

public static class MyViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textViewP006;
    public MyViewHolder2(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewP006=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewP006);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returning 0 as your itemCount and it means you have no items in your `RecyclerView`

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

change that to

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return p006StrongClassList.size();
}
```